# Oracle Roles, Privileges, and custom types spread across different schemas

Tags: oracle, types, roles

I have a schema that contains the vast majority of tables on my project, DEV2.

Additionally, I have a schema that contains oracle custom types used by DEV2: PUBLIC_TYPES.

I want to be able to create triggers on DEV2 that access the roles in PUBLIC_TYPES, but would prefer to do this with a role, so that when I create DEV3 (a clone of DEV2), I can just grant the role to DEV3 prior to compiling the triggers.

At the moment, if I perform the following:

```
grant all on public_types.type_name to DEV2;
```

and then (on the DEV2 user) I type:

```
desc public_types.type_name;
```

I get the proper description of the type.

However, if I instead do the following:

```
create role TABLE_PRIVS;
grant all on public_types.type_name_2 to TABLE_PRIVS;
grant table_privs to DEV2;
```

(and then switch to my DEV2 user, and desc)

```
desc public_types.type_name_2
```

I get

```
ORA-04043: object public_types.type_name_2 does not exist
```

What am I missing? I've granted the privilege to a role, and the role to a user. Does this work differently with types?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add role to user as default

```
grant table_privs to DEV2;
ALTER USER DEV2 DEFAULT ROLE table_privs;
```

otherwise you need to use [SET ROLE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10004.htm)

Comment: Thank you! Defaulting the role did it. It seems odd to me that you have to activate the role after granting it.